# Inserting items to collection view fail with XCTestCase

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xctest

#### TL;DR

I've made example project to show error. You can clone or download it from:

https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO45820305

And try to run tests on scheme SO45820305Testing. It will crash

---

#### Question:

I have code that is responsible for paginated list in my app. Whenever new data comes and it's parsed it append data to model in my VC and inserting in into `UICollectionView`:

```
func appendNewData(_ dataSet: [ExampleData]) {
    let currentItemsCount = self.collectionViewDataSet.count
    self.collectionViewDataSet.append(contentsOf: dataSet)
    var paths: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath]()
    for i in currentItemsCount...(currentItemsCount+dataSet.count-1) {
        paths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
    }
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at: paths) /* crash on this line */
    }) { _ in
        //print("done")
    }
}
```

And this works great when the app launch normally. So I would like to have this method tested. So I wrote a simple test:

```
func testAppendNewData() {
    self.viewController.collectionViewDataSet = [ExampleData]()
    self.viewController.collectionView.reloadData()
    let newDataSet = [ExampleData(), ExampleData()]
    self.viewController.appendNewData(newDataSet)
    ...
}
```

So going step by step by this test is:

1. I have none data in my `collectionViewDataSet`. Object is initialized but counter should be 0
2. Then I create two example objects and try to append it to my model.
3. Then there is some more in this test (assert to check sucessfully added things to model). But it's crashed here with error:

> error: -[Project.TestClass testAppendNewData]
>   : failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "Invalid update:
>   invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained
>   in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the
>   number of items contained in that section before the update (2), plus
>   or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (2
>   inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into
>   or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)."

So error say that my calculation was wrong for items, but actually `must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (2),` bother me. How this two items end up BEFORE update? And the funny thing is. How does it work in production app and does not work in test framework?

EDIT:
@fishinear point out correctly, I should not change a content without reloading data so i update my code. Now it's like above **but still causing the same issue**.

Comment: Another guess: you need to put the changes to the data source inside the `performBatchUpdates` block. Or remove the `performBatchUpdates` altogether, you don't need it because you have only one `insertItems` call.

Comment: I removed it completely and doesn't work either. But of course works in app framework not a testing one

Comment: Ah, of course, yes. Then I am out of ideas. You might wanna put in some log statements to verify whether what the error is saying is correct, and then debug from there.

Comment: Thanks @fishinear for help. If you're still willing to help I made example project that reproduce this issue. It's on top in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the tests, `numberOfItemsInSection` doesn't invoke before `self.collectionView.insertItems(at: paths)` and that's the reason of your crash.

Solution is put `self.viewController.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)` before `viewController.appendNewData(["a","b","c","d"])`

Comment: Just discovered it myself as well. Do you know the reason for this? It looks like some kind of delayed initialisation is going on?

Comment: `UICollectionView` is invisible during unit testing. iOS probably doesen't invoke methods related with invisible elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the complete contents of the data source, without telling the collection view about it:

```
self.viewController.collectionViewDataSet = [ExampleData]()
```

You should call `reloadData` after that, to update the collection view:

```
self.viewController.collectionViewDataSet = [ExampleData]()
self.viewController.collectionView.reloadData()

let newDataSet = [ExampleData(), ExampleData()]
self.viewController.appendNewData(newDataSet)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work, I've even tried without putting any content there, just calling `reloadData()` right before `self.viewController.appendNewData` still got the same issue.